# Debugger on VS Code is not working on Python with Output: DAP Server launched with command: conda run -n MyEnvironment --no-capture-output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using the Debugger on VS Code since a while for debugging Python scripts and it always worked fine.

Yesterday I tried to work on some scripts written on C-Language and debugging them .. Now the Debugger on VS Code is not working on the Python scripts.

**Looking on the Output window on the Python section, I could see the following error (Also figure is shown below):**

```
DAP Server launched with command: conda run -n testenv --no-capture-output --live-stream python c:\Users\user.name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter
```

I tried to un-install the Python extension on VS Code and re-install it again but it didn't solve the problem. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Could you show the output of the terminal？

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by upgrading my python version>=3.7.

Since I found I manually run this cmd:

```
c:\Users\user.name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter
```

The debugger does not support python3.6 or lower version.

Comment: How do you know that the debugger does not support python 3.6?  I have been debugging Python3.6 successfully for a long time in VSCode.   Is this a recent change?  Seeing as how many people in the world are stuck on Python2, I find it hard to believe that they would deprecate those versions in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade the python extension may solve the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/724858/vscode-debugger-not-working-for-python.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wade for your feedback and suggestion .. Unfortunately, after trying several options, the problem was only solved by uninstalling VSCode completely and starting again from a new one.

Comment: Thank you so much! Version `2022.4.0` works with Python 3.6.